# How to get counts for more than one code depending on the attributes

Tags: xml, xquery

I am using XQuery to count occurrences of both appearance related comments, and objectification comments, on a thread on Social Media. However, I want to count them according to the gender of the commenters.

So far I have got XQuery to return the count all the occurrences of appearance comments according to their genders by using this:

```
for $sex in ("female", "male")
for $t in doc ("MEN.xml")
return count($t/thread/comment[@gender=$sex]/appearance)
```

I also have found that if I adjust the return line, to this:

```
return count($t/thread/comment[@gender=$sex]/objectification)
```

it pulls out the count for objectification comments according to gender instead. However I was wondering if there was a way I could combine the two, so I get all the counts I need with one XQuery.

So far I have come up with this:

```
for $a in ("appearance", "objectification")
for $sex in ("female", "male")
for $t in doc ("MEN.xml")
return count($t/thread/comment[@gender=$sex]/$a)
```

However, it doesn't pull out the counts that we need.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: An excellent resource for learning XQuery is the Wikibook for it. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
let $t := fn:doc(“MEN.xml”)
return 
    for $a in (“appearance”, “objectification”)
    return
        for $sex in (“female”, “male”)
        return
           fn:count($t/thread/comment[@gender = $sex]/*[fn:local-name(.) = $a])
```